# How to access a running nodemon script after closing and reopening the terminal?

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal, nodemon

I'm running a node.js script using nodemon, but I'm wondering if it's possible to reaccess the nodemon process using the terminal after closing it.

Normally I would type "npm run start" that points to a "nodemon index.js" in the package.json, and some yellow and green logs would appear to tell the state of the process(starting, restarting). But if I close the terminal, how can I access this process again, without having to type another "npm run start"?

Just the case nodemon is not suitable for that, I would like to know which tools could help me achieve that, such as pm2, etc.

Comment: Run it in a screen or tmux session. This permits the terminal to be disconnected from the program and reconnected later.

Comment: It worked out for me using tmux sessions, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a screen or tmux session, and then run your app.
This permits the terminal to be disconnected from the program and reconnected later by reviving the same session.

Answer (score 0):

cntr+j leaves your server running in the background, then if you work on the code and saves it and the server crashes because the server is still running.

A solution is just to minimize the terminal and not to close it, or opening via command prompt.